# JSON Output from readdir

Tags: php, json

i am a little bit confused.

I have a folder with some pdf Documents and this code:

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir('c:/dateien/');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
$dateiinfo = pathinfo($dir."/".$file);
$string = $dateiinfo['filename'];
$array = explode("_", $string);
if ($dateiinfo['extension'] == "pdf") {
$files[] = $array;
}   
}
echo json_encode($files);
```

This is my Output Result

```
[["Titel","2014-01-13","2014-01-14"],["Titel","2014-01-15","2014-01-15"]]
```

But i want to use it in fullcalendar. I need title: Titel and start: 2014-01-13 and so on.

Has anynone an idea to solve my problem?

The file name is like this title_start_end.pdf

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
...
$files[] = array(
  'title' => $array[0],
  'start' => $array[1],
  'end' => $array[2]
);
...
```

Comment: I get this Error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in XXX on line 17 This is 'title' => $array[0],

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Also, just in case, you should not include the '...' in your actual code.

Comment: No the ... are not included

Comment: Did you paste it exactly?  What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I just tested the code that is giving you a problem and it works.  Can you paste the block as well as 3 lines before and after?

Comment: Here is my Code:

    $string = $dateiinfo['filename'];

    $array = explode("_", $string);
 
    if ($dateiinfo['extension'] == "pdf") {
 
    $files[] = $array(
    'title' => $array[0],
    'start' => $array[1],
    'end' => $array[2]
     );  
     } 
     }
     echo json_encode($files);</pre>

Comment: "$files[] = $array(" should be "$files[] = array("

Comment: Oh my god. I copy your code only behind array..... THANKS for your help, now it works!!!